# Finding closed or numeric value for $\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x \csc (a x)}{x^2+b^2} \, dx$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

According to Gradshteyn 3.747-3 $\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x \csc (a x)}{x^2+b^2} \, dx=\frac{\pi}{2\sinh(ab)}$ $b>0$

[image: Gradshteyn]

so I'm trying to get some numeric results from Mathematica 12.

```
a = 6; b = 12;

NIntegrate[(x/((x^2 + b^2) Sin[a x])), {x, 0, Infinity}, MaxRecursion -> 12]
```

However this does not match the values given by

```
Pi/(2*Sinh[a*b])
```

So it is not clear where I'm going wrong.

Comment: How did you evaluate the `NIntegrate` for undefined parameters `a,b `? Please show some code!

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann I just did a = 6; b = 12; but I also just put them in manually too to be sure.

Comment: There are singularities in the integral when a*x = Pi *k for some integer k, and when the intergral goes through the point x = b

Comment: @flinty is there any code to deal with these?

Comment: You can inform it of the singularities with `Exclusions -> {x == b, Sin[a*x] == 0}` but this doesn't fix it.

Comment: The integrand has residues of `(k \[Pi] (-1)^k)/(a (b^2 + k^2 \[Pi]^2))` along the reals where k is an integer, and two poles along the imaginary axis. It's likely the book result was reached by contour integration of a big arc that  expands to infinity and shrinks around these poles. Have you checked the errata? It's surprising to me at least, that this integral converges, so it could be a [mistake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradshteyn_and_Ryzhik) _On the downsides, Gradshteyn and Ryzhik has become known to contain a relatively high number of typographical errors even in newer editions_

Comment: ^ 3-747.3 seems to be discussed here on page 9. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/273158286_The_integral_formula_of_Poisson_with_principal_value_integrals_and_some_special_Gradshteyn_and_Ryzhik_integrals

Comment: Is this taken as a principal valued integral? The integrand has poles of order 1 at each singularity on the positive real axis.

Comment: @ChipHurst the above article suggests it is a principal value integral so it doesn't converge normally. You could use `Method -> PrincipalValue` but there are infinitely many poles, so how to specify all the exclusions ?

Comment: I’m not sure you can specify an infinite amount of singularities with `NIntegrate`.

Comment: @flinty You could split the integration range into subintervals with one singularity `k Pi` , this gives an infinite sum...

Answer (score 5):

I want to focus on the numerics here. There is a way to do this integral taking infinite number of singularities into account.

One can split the integral into the domains containing only one singularity at $a x_n=\pi n$, i.e. $x\in[x_n-\frac{\pi}{2a},x_n+\frac{\pi}{2a}]$ and an integral in the interval $x\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2a}]$. On the last step we use `NSum` with some options. The options are very important. Consider first my failed attempt:

```
Clear[f]
f[n_?NumericQ,a_,b_]:=NIntegrate[(x/((x^2+b^2) Sin[a x])),{x,(π n)/a-π/(2a),(π n)/a,(π n)/a+π/(2a)},WorkingPrecision->100,Method->PrincipalValue]
f0[a_,b_]:=NIntegrate[(x/((x^2+b^2) Sin[a x])),{x,0,π/(2a)},WorkingPrecision->100]

f0[6,12]+NSum[f[n,6,12],{n,1,∞},Method>"AlternatingSigns",WorkingPrecision->100]
Out[1]= 6.39989549924364176901258523623081516506764870738550937643852237103123602088582134002479513849115*10^-6
```

The numerical value seems to be highly accurate and well converged, but is different from the analytic one

```
e[a_,b_]:=N[Pi/(2*Sinh[a*b]),100] 
e[6,12]
Out[2]= 1.690235331526788818439805170791473807196429480676031631266783609275102725281157127348346908376558298*10^-31
```

The discrepancy can be corrected by changing the default `NSumTerms` value. Let us introduce the relative error as a function of this parameter

```
relErr[a_,b_,k_]:=Abs[f0[a,b]+NSum[f[n,a,b],{n,1,∞},
                               Method->"AlternatingSigns",
                               WorkingPrecision->100,
                               NSumTerms->k]
                      -e[a,b]]/Abs[e[a,b]]//N
```

and try a few values:

```
relErr[6,12,21]
Out[3]= 3.78639*10^25
relErr[6,12,22]
Out[4]= 2.38766*10^-68
relErr[6,12,25]
Out[5]= 2.3903*10^-68
```

Thus, it is important to explicitly consider the first 22 terms!

Comment: It should be noticed that `f0[6, 12] + 
 NSum[f[n, 6, 12], {n, 1, \[Infinity]}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]` performs `0.*10^-7`.

Comment: You don't take into account the singularity at the origin in your `f0[a_,b_]`.

Comment: @user64494 Thank you for checking other options. 1. According to the documentation one needs to "use a method for alternating series to get a very precise sum approximation".  2. This is a removable singularity (the limit $x\rightarrow 0$) is finite.

Comment: -1. In you answer you use `e[a_,b_]:=N[Pi/(2*Sinh[a*b]),100] `. Imagine you don't know it. Such sort answer does not make a good impression.

Comment: I'd like to add that the `NSumTerms->k` option means you consider a truncated sum and that sum is a sum for the principal value of the integral over $(0,\frac {\pi k} a)$. This is not the required result.

Comment: @user64494 I think your criticism, especially on the `NSumTerms->k` is unjustified. This option is not equivalent to the truncated sum. Otherwise, one would simply write `Sum[..,{i,1,k}]`. As for the a priory knowledge of the answer---I partially accept the criticism that it is not a fully automatic, black box solution. Indeed a human intervention was required to notice the convergence plateau. A careful mathematician would notice this peculiarity without knowing the exact result. But I was guided by it. By the way, I like your solution, and just wanted to show a numerical alternative.

Answer (score 4):

Using the substitution  `u==a x` the identity is transformed to `Integrate[u/((u^2 + ab^2) Sin[u]), {u, 0, Infinity}] == Pi/(2 Sinh[ab])`

The integral is singular at `u==k Pi, k=1,2,...` and the integration range is splitted into subintervals (similar to @yarchik answer) containing only one singularity (thanks to @flinty  and @ ChipHurst comments):

```
int[ab_?NumericQ, n_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[u/((u^2 + ab^2) Sin[u]) , {u, 0, Pi/2}] +
Sum[ NIntegrate[u/((u^2 + ab^2) Sin[u]) , {u, k Pi - Pi/2, k Pi + Pi/2},Method -> PrincipalValue, Exclusions -> {u == k Pi}], {k, 1, n} ]
```

This finite sum matchs quite well:

```
Plot[{int[ab, 10], Pi/(2 Sinh[ab])}, {ab, 0, 1},PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.01],Lighter[Blue]}, Red}, 
PlotLabel ->"{int[ab,10],\!\(\*FractionBox[\(Pi\), \(2\\\ Sinh[ab]\)]\)}",AxesLabel -> {"ab ", None}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is a modification of the @yarchik's approach.

Comment: +1. `int[ab, Infinity]` works well to me. I think you give a correct numerical answer.

Comment: @user64494 Thanks, the "modification" shows a straightforward approach. Ticky idea `int[ab, Infinity]`

Comment: I changed my mind. In fact, it does not work: `int[72, Infinity]` returns the input. I was missed by the plot of ` Pi/(2 Sinh[ab]`.

Comment: Finite sum works!

Comment: Yes, your code works well say for $n=30$. This is an advantage of yours.

Comment: Since you started to explore the whole parameter space, can you extend you curve to the values of `a` and `b` as in the OP.

Comment: @yarchik `Map[int[72, #] &, {10, 100, 1000 } ]` evaluates to `{0.000190688, -0.000015741, -1.85136*10^-7}`  indicating "numerical convergence"  towards the expected value  `Pi/(2 Sinh[72] (*O[10^-31] *)`

Comment: Actually I do not see any convergence. Being heavily criticized by @user64494 for my answer, which rigorously provides 10^-68 relative error, I do not consider this to be an accurate solution.

Comment: @yarchik Your solution is great!  I tried to avoid such high values `WorkingPrecision->100` in my answer. You can't see convergence in my comment, but a trend of decaying values.

Answer (score 3):

Following the  @flinty's comment, we obtain

```
Residue[x/(x^2 + b^2)/Sin[a*x], {x, π/a*n},  Assumptions -> n ∈ Integers]
(*((-1)^-n n π)/(a^2 b^2 + n^2 π^2)*)

Sum[%, {n, -∞, ∞}]
(*0*)
```

and

```
2*π*I*Residue[x/(x^2 + b^2)/Sin[a*x], {x, I*b}]
(*π Csch[a b]*)
```

Now, making use of the Jordan's lemma, we conclude that
$$PV\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac x {(x^2+b^2)\sin(ax)}\,dx= \pi  \text{csch}(a b).$$
It remains to apply the parity of the integrand.